# PHP Singleton returns different values with spl_object_hash

Tags: php, laravel, singleton

I'm creating a singleton with PHP like this.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\classes\Test;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    private static $test_obj;

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        if (self::$test_obj === null) {
            self::$test_obj = new Test();
        }
        return self::$test_obj;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to test the code like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $test_obj = TestController::get();
        dd(spl_object_hash($test_obj));
    }
}
```

At this point it returns different hash values. But it's supposed to return the same hash value since this is a Singleton right?

Note - spl_object_id() always returns the same object id though.

Comment: but I initialize a new Test() when only this condition fulfills -  if (self::$test_obj === null)

Comment: I have a route which points to MainController-->index(). So I trigger that route in the browser to test. When triggering it 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc time dd() gives a different hash value.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all with a basic test case. Assuming this is all done within the same request the value should remain the same

Comment: @apokryfos - Interesting. Yup, this is all done within the same request the value should remain the same. But in my case when I call to this route each time it gives a different hash value.

Comment: How are you calling this route? If you're using the router it may be creating a new controller instance

Comment: @apokryfos - A good point. I'm using Laravel routes since I was using Laravel for this. So the route is like this - Route::get('/test', 'MainController@index'); But it seems a static method for get.

Comment: @apokryfos, you are correct!!

Comment: I tried the same code in Core PHP without Laravel. But surprisingly I encounter the same issue!!